# Why is require in this example a method and not a variable?

Tags: ruby

I'm going through Why's Poignant Guide. I don't understand why 'require' in the first line is a method and not a variable:

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.start( 'www.ruby-lang.org', 80 ) do |http|
  print( http.get( '/en/about/license.txt' ).body )
end
```

Comment: I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Because it invokes a Ruby message send, what is more commonly called a function in other languages. This particular 'function' loads an external piece of code referenced by the name 'net/http'.  Sometimes syntactical elements such as parenthesies are omitted as a syntactical convenience, so it may not look exactly like other functions or Ruby message sends.

This description will not help you understand *why* this is the practice in Ruby because you need to learn a significant number of the syntactical patterns before realizing the intent of their design. Once you realize this design intent you have the answer to 'why' this syntax was chosen. Alternatively you could research the Ruby design discussions.

Comment: how would a beginner, such as myself, come to that conclusion though? What tells me it is invoking a function?

Comment: You're going to have to keep reading and learning. Those things become clear as you learn.

Comment: This is *not* a function invocation. Ruby doesn't have functions. It is a message send.

Comment: @J.M.Habibi: It takes an argument. In Ruby, variables don't take arguments, only message sends do, so it can only be a message send, nothing else. That's just part of the basic syntax and semantics. You will have to learn at least the basics of the syntax and semantics in order to understand even the most basic code. Knowing that, for example, only message sends take arguments, and only method definitions and blocks have parameter lists, and that instance variables start with an `@` sign, and so on is part of that basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be a variable, because there no such piece of language syntax that consists of a variable and a string literal separated by a space.

Ergo, this must be a method call (message send).

Answer (score 0):

The scope for a local variable is pretty much narrow. In case an expression is ambiguous between a local variable and a method, if you look within the current method body, class body, block, etc., and cannot find the local variable assignment, then it would be interpreted as a method.

Answer (score 0):

Because it takes an argument. In Ruby, only message sends have arguments.